# Making a copy of an entire namespace?

Tags: python

I'd like to make a copy of an entire namespace while replacing some functions with dynamically constructed versions.

In other words, starting with namespace (`import tensorflow as tf`), I want to make a copy of it, replace some functions with my own versions, and update `__globals__` of all the symbols to stay within the new namespace. This needs to be done in topological order of dependency.

I started doing something like it [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tPCaS89mb83lNTHSAa9-tC94s42aWpXw8MaZEhLZzVE/edit) but now I'm starting to wonder if I'm reinventing the wheel. Care is needed to deal with circular dependencies in system modules, functions/types/objects need to be updated differently, etc.

Can anyone point to existing code that solves a similar task?

Comment: It sounds like you're going to run into problems like circular imports messing up your nice topological order and C modules not calling your replacement functions.

Comment: I don't have C modules calling Python functions, so only looking to clone Python functions. How does Python itself deal with circular imports? (isn't it an error?)

Comment: Circular imports aren't inherently an error, but they're usually a bad idea. If a circular import causes you to try to import a module while it's in the middle of initialization, you get the half-initialized module object. This means that `from` imports and other things that rely on the module being initialized won't work.

Comment: I think we would need a bit more context.  *Why* are you trying to do this?  What is your ultimate goal?  Why isn't monkey-patching the functions you want to replace enough?

Comment: Because I want to have access to both functionalities. I'm creating a custom version of "tf" module, say "tfi", and I want the user to be able to use both new and old functionality in the same program, under names "tf" and "tfi". Here's the tracking [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2334)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, do you want to be able to access this functionality _using the same module name_?

Comment: Different module names. I'm appending "immediate." to all the modules affected when rewriting the dependent hierarchy

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, well, this is what the code in my answer does. I've updated it, and now it doesn't kinda overwrite the `string` namespace.

Comment: why not just make a copy on the filesystem with a new module name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To patch a set of functions while importing second instances of a set of functions, you can override the standard Python import hook and apply the patches directly at import time.  This will make sure that no other module will ever see the unpatched versions of any of the modules, so even if they import functions from another module directly by name, they will only see the patched functions.  Here is a proof-of-concept implementation:

```
import __builtin__
import collections
import contextlib
import sys


@contextlib.contextmanager
def replace_import_hook(new_import_hook):
    original_import = __builtin__.__import__
    __builtin__.__import__ = new_import_hook
    yield original_import
    __builtin__.__import__ = original_import


def clone_modules(patches, additional_module_names=None):
    """Import new instances of a set of modules with some objects replaced.

    Arguments:
      patches - a dictionary mapping `full.module.name.symbol` to the new object.
      additional_module_names - a list of the additional modules you want new instances of, without
          replacing any objects in them.

    Returns:
      A dictionary mapping module names to the new patched module instances.
    """

    def import_hook(module_name, *args):
        result = original_import(module_name, *args)
        if module_name not in old_modules or module_name in new_modules:
            return result
        # The semantics for the return value of __import__() are a bit weird, so we need some logic
        # to determine the actual imported module object.
        if len(args) >= 3 and args[2]:
            module = result
        else:
            module = reduce(getattr, module_name.split('.')[1:], result)
        for symbol, obj in patches_by_module[module_name].items():
            setattr(module, symbol, obj)
        new_modules[module_name] = module
        return result

    # Group patches by module name
    patches_by_module = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    for dotted_name, obj in patches.items():
        module_name, symbol = dotted_name.rsplit('.', 1)  # Only allows patching top-level objects
        patches_by_module[module_name][symbol] = obj

    try:
        # Remove the old module instances from sys.modules and store them in old_modules
        all_module_names = list(patches_by_module)
        if additional_module_names is not None:
            all_module_names.extend(additional_module_names)
        old_modules = {}
        for name in all_module_names:
            old_modules[name] = sys.modules.pop(name)

        # Re-import modules to create new patched versions
        with replace_import_hook(import_hook) as original_import:
            new_modules = {}
            for module_name in all_module_names:
                import_hook(module_name)
    finally:
        sys.modules.update(old_modules)
    return new_modules
```

And here some test code for this implementation:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import math
import random

def patched_log(x):
    print('Computing log({:g})'.format(x))
    return math.log(x)

patches = {'math.log': patched_log}
cloned_modules = clone_modules(patches, ['random'])
new_math = cloned_modules['math']
new_random = cloned_modules['random']
print('Original log:         ', math.log(2.0))
print('Patched log:          ', new_math.log(2.0))
print('Original expovariate: ', random.expovariate(2.0))
print('Patched expovariate:  ', new_random.expovariate(2.0))
```

The test code has this output:

```
Computing log(4)
Computing log(4.5)
Original log:          0.69314718056
Computing log(2)
Patched log:           0.69314718056
Original expovariate:  0.00638038735379
Computing log(0.887611)
Patched expovariate:   0.0596108277801
```

The first two lines of output result from [these two lines in `random`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l60), which are executed at import time.  This demonstrates that `random` sees the patched function right away.  The rest of the output demonstrates that the original `math` and `random` still use the unpatched version of `log`, while the cloned modules both use the patched version.

A cleaner way of overriding the import hook might be to use a *meta import hook* as defined in [PEP 302](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/), but providing a full implementation of that approach is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: for posterity: when I tried this approach on tensorflow, it caused problems because of its reliance on `isinstance`. I'm passing in objects from the original namespace, so `isinstance` returns false because it compared against the copied type. So instead of "copy everything" I needed to copy the minimal set needed to make sure the patched function references are updated successfully, so I went back to original method with extra modifications to deal with closures/default values

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to make a copy of the contents of a module and patch everything in it to use the correct globals, you could trick Python into importing everything you want to copy a second time.  This will give you a newly initialized copy of all modules, so it won't copy any global state the modules might have (not sure whether you would need that).

```
import importlib
import sys

def new_module_instances(module_names):
    old_modules = {}
    for name in module_names:
        old_modules[name] = sys.modules.pop(name)
    new_modules = {}
    for name in module_names:
        new_modules[name] = importlib.import_module(name)
    sys.modules.update(old_modules)
    return new_modules
```

Note that we first delete *all* modules we want to replace from `sys.modules`, so they all get import a second time, and the dependencies between these modules are set up correctly automatically.  At the end of the function, we restore the original state of `sys.modules`, so everything else continues to see the original versions of these modules.

Here's an example:

```
>>> import logging.handlers
>>> new_modules = new_module_instances(['logging', 'logging.handlers'])
>>> logging_clone = new_modules['logging']
>>> logging
<module 'logging' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.pyc'>
>>> logging_clone
<module 'logging' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.pyc'>
>>> logging is logging_clone
False
>>> logging is logging.handlers.logging
True
>>> logging_clone is logging_clone.handlers.logging
True
```

The last three expressions show that the two versions of logging are different modules, and both versions of the `handlers` module use the correct version of the `logging` module.

Comment: I indeed don't care about module state. This + regular monkeypatching seems a lot simpler than what I was doing, will try it out to see if there are any gotchas.

Comment: It seems that I still need to recursively examine all symbols in the module hierarchy when doing function replacement, because some module could have stored the reference to the function with `import myfunc as saved_copy`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: This is a separate problem, and it wasn't quite clear from your question that you need to solve this as well.  This problem occurs whenever you want to monkey-patch a function everywhere it is used, and it's not specific to your situation.  However, your specific situation might make it easier to solve this problem than it usually is.  Does the solution have to work in Python 2 and 3, or would a solution only working in Python 3 be fine as well?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov: Ignore my last question, I just thought of a simple solution that works in both Python 2 and 3.  Since I think the code in this answer is useful on its own, I'll post a new answer with an alternate approach.

Comment: I definitely need it to work in Python 2 because that's what's officially supported for tensorflow, extra Python 3 support never hurts of course.

Comment: Oh, and please note that this code doesn't use context managers yet to make sure the import hook is restored, so it will likely mess up your Python interpreter due to bugs.  I'll get back to this tomorrow.

Comment: BTW, I got something that works for functions and modules [here](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/immediate/python/immediate/module_rewriter.py). But, 1) code is complicated 2) doesn't follow dependencies in classes and objects and 3) no idea about Python 3 compatibility

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I recommend against the approach you took in the linked file.  This way lies madness.  The two instances of each module you get will be linked in subtle ways.  From a quick glance at the code, I can already tell that new functions share closure cells, default arguments and attributes with the original function, so they aren't properly decoupled.  There are lots of bugs of this kind, and there will always be yet another special case you didn't cover.   The prototype I linked above is broken as well, but it can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

To my mind, you can do this easily:

```
import imp, string

st = imp.load_module('st', *imp.find_module('string')) # copy the module

def my_upper(a):
    return "a" + a

def my_lower(a):
    return a + "a"

st.upper = my_upper
st.lower = my_lower


print string.upper("hello") # HELLO
print string.lower("hello") # hello

print st.upper("hello") # ahello
print st.lower("hello") # helloa
```

And when you call `st.upper("hello")`, it will result in `"hello"`.

So, you don't really need to mess with globals.

Comment: Yes, that works, but I actually need to retain both old and new functionalities of string, so I need to make a copy. IE, I don't want to change every user of "string" to use new version of upper, but only change it in a specific module.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, no problem, `my_string = st; my_string.upper = test`. Edit: no, there _is_ a problem here, wait...

Comment: So I have a module with some functions and dependencies. I want to make copy of this module, so that when calling functions from it, eventually some function may call "string.upper" which goes to custom version. However, also want to retain access to original/unpatched module, where "upper" functionality is unchanged

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, I think I solved that problem, take a look at my updated answer

Comment: OK, that works for code in the snippet. But now the issue would be to make a copy of module, so that functions in that module, or any functions called from that those functions, always use the patched version.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, I don't understand what you just said, could you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: IE, I want to make a copy of a module, say "httplib", and call it "httplib_patched", so that whenever I call functions from "httplib_patched", the new version of "upper" is used. But original "httplib" module is unchanged

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that makes a copy of a module, can you give an example with httplib?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, maybe you need to reload the page. There is a comment saying `# copy the module`. This is the line to do copying: `st = imp.load_module('st', *imp.find_module('httplib'))`

Comment: If you copy httplib like `*imp.find_module('httplib')`, how do you ensure that calls to `string.upper` in the copied module go to your patched version?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, no, I copy the module with `imp.load_module`, which _reloads the given module_ into a separate object which you can modify as you want

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, wait, `string.upper` is the original while `st.upper` is patched.

Comment: So I need to modify this separate object, say `httplib_patched` to make sure that any references to affected functions, like `upper` are updated to point to patched versions. This is complicated by the fact that functions in `httplib` may be calling `upper` indirectly, through a chain of helper functions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112585/discussion-between-forcebru-and-yaroslav-bulatov).

Comment: I think there is a bit missing to get what Yaroslav asked for.  Simply import a single module again doesn't solve the problem.  You need to be able to import multiple modules again and have the dependencies between them set up correctly.  You can still trick Python's import machinery into doing this for you by first removing all modules you want to replace from `sys.modules`, but using only the code in this answer isn't enough.