# Dealing with circular dependency (functools -> _functools -> functools) when copying namespace

Tags: python

Module `functools`  refers to `reduce` which is defined in `_functools`.
Meanwhile `_functools` refers to `partial` which is defined in `functools`

I'm running into this problem when trying to create a copy of namespace for monkey-patching purposes. But in my case, I need both old and monkey-patched functionality, hence need for a copy. Any suggestion what's a good way to circular dependencies like this?

Using `Python 2.7.10`

Some source code per request

```
def _get_dependent_modules(m):
  """Return set of all modules defining symbols in given module."""

  modules = set()
  for symbol_name, symbol in m.__dict__.items():
    if hasattr(symbol, '__module__'):
        if symbol.__module__ in sys.modules:
          print "Symbol %s, defined in %s" % (symbol_name, symbol.__module__)
          modules.add(sys.modules[symbol.__module__])
        else:
          print "Cant find module for %s" %(symbol)
  return modules

_get_dependent_modules(functools)

Symbol wraps, defined in functools
Symbol partial, defined in functools
Symbol update_wrapper, defined in functools
Symbol total_ordering, defined in functools
Symbol reduce, defined in _functools
Symbol cmp_to_key, defined in functools

_get_dependent_modules(sys.modules["_functools"])

Symbol partial, defined in functools
Symbol reduce, defined in _functools
```

Comment: It seems `reduce` is in both. You can see `reduce` in `functools` with `sys.modules["functools"].__dict__["reduce"]`

Comment: updated with some source code

Comment: So if I'm dynamically rewriting modules, which one should should I rewrite first? Since reduce is defined in `_functools` I need to copy all symbols in `_functools` and update all of `__globals__` of  those symbols to point to the new module. But since `_functools` has reference to `partial` defined in `functools`, I should rewrite `functools` first. But that's a circular dependency

Comment: I started a bounty on a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37281928/making-a-copy-of-an-entire-namespace

Comment: Note that if you try to get/set `functools.partial.__globals__` you get an error. Does that affect what you're trying to do?

Comment: No, because I'm making a copy, so I'm setting globals to new value during constructions

Comment: I'm getting globals from sys.modules[functools.partial.__module]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remember what you have seen ([identity comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(object-oriented_programming))) so far and not iterate over or descend into stuff you remember.

Perhaps I'm not understanding the complexity of the operation (copy namespace).

Just a suggestion:

```
sub scan_symbols(object):
    for each member in object:
        if member is of type-primitive:
            whatever
        if member is of type-object:
            record member reference if not already recorded
            if reference is new:
                scan_symbols(member)
```

Real code example in PHP:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pradosoft/prado/master/framework/Util/TVarDumper.php

This one avoids circular deps as well:

https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper